# listview option button selected automatically

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button, android-custom-view

i have custom listview in this i am using radio button , if i select the 1st listitem , automatically the listview last item is also selected how to avoid this problem?

here is my code:

in adapter class:

```
public class QuestionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public QuestionsAdapter(Context context, List<Question> data) {
    super(context, R.layout.questions_lits_item, data);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Question question = getItem(position);
    View view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.questions_lits_item, null, true);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    RadioButton option1, option2, option3, option4;
    option1 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option1);
    option2 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option2);
    option3 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option3);
    option4 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option4);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.question)).setText((position + 1)+ ". " + question.getQuestion());
    option1.setText(question.getOption1());
    option2.setText(question.getOption2());
    if (!question.getOption3().isEmpty()) {
        option3.setText(question.getOption3());
    } else {
        option3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (!question.getOption4().isEmpty()) {
        option4.setText(question.getOption4());
    } else {
        option4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    option1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            question.setSelectedAnswer(question.getOption1());
        }
    });
    option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            question.setSelectedAnswer(question.getOption2());
        }
    });
    option3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            question.setSelectedAnswer(question.getOption3());
        }
    });
    option4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            question.setSelectedAnswer(question.getOption4());
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

> List : Question is a class with getter and setter method

```
package com.griffin.android.schoolapp.adapter;
```

public class Question {

```
private String id;
private String question;
private String option1;
private String option2;
private String option3;
private String option4;
private String selectedAnswer = "null";

public Question(String id, String question, String option1, String option2,
        String option3, String option4) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.question = question;
    this.option1 = option1;
    this.option2 = option2;
    this.option3 = option3;
    this.option4 = option4;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getOption1() {
    return option1;
}

public void setOption1(String option1) {
    this.option1 = option1;
}

public String getOption2() {
    return option2;
}

public void setOption2(String option2) {
    this.option2 = option2;
}

public String getOption3() {
    return option3;
}

public void setOption3(String option3) {
    this.option3 = option3;
}

public String getOption4() {
    return option4;
}

public void setOption4(String option4) {
    this.option4 = option4;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return question;
}

public String getSelectedAnswer() {
    return selectedAnswer;
}

public void setSelectedAnswer(String selectedAnswer) {
    this.selectedAnswer = selectedAnswer;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly `setCheckedId()` the radio button ID that should be checked, just like how your set text and visibility, because the item view will be recycled, every time `getView` is called it will either inflate a new view/recycle an existing one, in which case it may carry over the selected state of another item.

Also try to use [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern for better UI performance.